# Applying color adjustments to an image

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

how I can apply color adjustment to an image in windows phone. Is there any free sdk is available that support color adjustment. In my application I need to apply a color shade to an image based on the color he selected from color pellet. Can anyone please help me to implement such functionality in windows phone.

Comment: When you say Color adjustment, do you mean a Mask? Meaning, if the user selects blue, then the image has a bluish tinge. Is this what you aim to achieve?

Comment: yup something similar to that, Do you have any idea about similar implementation

Comment: Yes, Please check the answer post. It should give you the method to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Place a rectangle over the Image and set its opacity to 60%. (It is easier if you use Expression Blend for this part).

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image Margin="188,208,168,299" Source="wifi-signal.jpg"/>
        <Rectangle Name="Rect1" Fill="Blue" Margin="188,208,167,299" Stroke="Black" Opacity="0.595"/>

    </Grid>
```

In the Code View, you can trigger an event, to change the color of the Rectangle using the following code:

```
Rect1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```